# Number of integer lattice points between two rational points

Tags: number-theory, coordinate-systems, integer-lattices

I'm trying to find a way to compute the number of integer lattice points $\left ( (x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \right )$ between two rational points $\left ( (p, q) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 \right )$.

Let $(p_1, q_1)$ and $(p_2, q_2)$ denote the points in question.

It's easy if both happen to be integer lattice points (which could happen since integers are also rationals,) you can use the method described in [this math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1341275/294504), which says it would be $\text{gcd}(q_2 - q_1, p_2 - p_1) + 1$ (including both endpoints.)

It's also straightforward if $q_1 = q_2$ (or $p_1 = p_2$). If $q_1 = q_2$ and $q_1 \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then it's zero. If $q_1 = q_2$ and $q_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then you basically cut off the ends of the segment until it's endpoints are integral. (i.e. if $p_1 < p_2$, consider the segment between $(\lceil p_1 \rceil, q_1)$ and $(\lfloor p_2 \rfloor, q_1)$, which would give you $\lfloor p_2 \rfloor - \lceil p_1 \rceil + 1$ points.)

But what if $(p_1, q_1), (p_2, q_2) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Z}^2$ with $q_1 \neq q_2$ and $p_1 \neq p_2$?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest to come back on what you already know for 2 points with integers coordinates. Find the closest integer point from both endpoints and apply your formula.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: Note that $[(p_1,q_1),(p_2,q_2)] = \lbrace t(p_2,q_2)+(1-t)(p_1,q_1) : t\in [0,1]\rbrace$ , so you want those $t\in [0,1]$ such that $tp_2+(1-t)p_1, tq_2+(1-t)q_1\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is not difficult to see that $t$ has to be rational.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the problem for integer coordinates after scaling?

Comment: @Bleuderk but how would you find the closest integer point then? It's not as simple as rounding up or down one of the coordinates...

Comment: @Servaes I don't think so, because if the segment stretches/squishes but the integer lattice doesn't, you'll change the number of points between the endpoints

Comment: If $d$ is the least common multiple of the denominators of $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$. Then scaling the plane by a factor $d$ in both directions maps them to points with integer coordinates, and maps points on the line with integer coordinates  to points on the line with integer multiples of $d$ as coordinates.

Comment: @Servaes If you wrote up a quick proof, I'd consider that a pretty good solution to this question!

Answer (score 1):

These are just a few thoughts, not a complete answer, but perhaps it helps.

---

The points between distinct points $(p_0,q_0),(p_1,q_1)\in\Bbb{Q}^2$ are the points of the form
$$(p_t,q_t):=t(p_1,q_1)+(1-t)(p_0,q_0),$$
with $t\in[0,1]$. Because $p_0,p_1,q_0,q_1\in\Bbb{Q}$, such a point is rational if and only if $t\in\Bbb{Q}$. The question is then for which rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ the two coordinates
$$p_t:=tp_1+(1-t)p_0
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
q_t:=tq_1+(1-t)q_0,$$
are both integers. Let $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i,r,s\in\Bbb{Z}$ be such that
$$p_i:=\frac{a_i}{b_i},\qquad q_i:=\frac{c_i}{d_i},\qquad t:=\frac{r}{s},$$
and all fractions are in reduced form with positive denominators. Then
$$p_t=\frac{a_1b_0r+a_0b_1(s-r)}{b_0b_1s}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
q_t=\frac{c_1d_0r+c_0d_1(s-r)}{d_0d_1s}.$$
In particular, because $r$ and $s$ are coprime, we see that $s$ must divide
$$a_1b_0-a_0b_1
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
c_1d_0-c_0d_1.$$
This means $s$ is a positive divisor of
$$\gcd(a_1b_0-a_0b_1,c_1d_0-c_0d_1).$$
This already gives an upper bound on the number of integer points on the line.

Moreover, we see that $b_1$ must divide $b_0r$ and $d_1$ must divide $d_0r$. This means $r$ is a multiple of
$$\operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac{b_1}{\gcd(b_0,b_1)},\frac{d_1}{\gcd(d_0,d_1)}\right).$$
Finally, we see that $b_0$ must divide $b_1(s-r)$ and $d_0$ must divide $d_1(s-r)$, so $s-r$ is a multiple of
$$\operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac{b_0}{\gcd(b_0,b_1)},\frac{d_0}{\gcd(d_0,d_1)}\right).$$

Comment: I considered using the $t \in [0,1]$ parameterization, but I wouldn't have gotten all the divisor and lcm stuff, so thank you! :D